# Optional arguments in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments, option-type, getopts

I am trying to write a function that has optional arguments in a way such that the optional arguments are follow by something like `-x`, for example

```
my_function man_arg1 man_arg2 -n opt_arg1 -o opt_arg2 -x opt_arg3
```

and I want this to also support callings like

```
my_function man_arg1 man_arg2 -x opt_arg
```

In other questions I see people suggesting using getopts but in those answers it seems like you have to specify all the optional arguments when calling the function? Also it still seems unclear to me how you would use getopts for this.

Comment: Typically you set a default value and then parse the arguments and overwrite the value if the flag is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question correctly, sorry if I don't answer it...

You could use (for example) `getopt(1)`, as below, which will allow `-x` option to be anywhere.
Please note that optional arguments (`man_arg*`) can also be anywhere.

```sh
#! /usr/bin/bash

# CMD is the shell-script name without directory (basename)
CMD="${0##*/}"

my_function() {
    # Some comments added per OP request

    # below variable is used by getopt's "-o" option (short options).
    # each letter is a possible option; colon following a letter means this
    # option will take a parameter. See getopt(1) for more details.
    SOPTS="n:o:x:"

    # output of getopt is assigned to TMP. For example, when calling :
    # my_function -n n1 a b -o o1 -x x1 c d
    # TMP will contain: "-n 'n1' -o 'o1' -x 'x1' -- 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'"
    TMP=$(getopt -o "$SOPTS" -n "$CMD" -- "$@") || exit 1

    # assign TMP to positional parameters $1, $2, etc...
    eval set -- "$TMP"
    unset TMP

    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            -n|-o)
                printf "[%s] argument: %s\n" "$1" "$2"
                shift
                ;;
            -x)
                printf "[-x] argument: %s\n" "$2"
                shift
                ;;
            --)                                       # end of options
                shift
                break
                ;;

        esac
        shift
    done

    nargs=$#
    printf "remaining %d args :\n" "$nargs"
    for ((i=0; i<nargs; ++i)); do
        printf "%d: %s\n" $((i + 1)) "$1"
        shift
    done
}

my_function "$@"
```

Examples:

```
br@lorien:~$ ./test-getopt.bash man_arg1 man_arg2 -n opt_arg1 -o opt_arg2 -x opt_arg3
[-n] argument: opt_arg1
[-o] argument: opt_arg2
[-x] argument: opt_arg3
remaining 2 args :
1: man_arg1
2: man_arg2

br@lorien:~$ ./test-getopt.bash man_arg1 man_arg2 -n opt_arg1 -o opt_arg2 -x opt_arg3 man_arg3 man_arg4
[-n] argument: opt_arg1
[-o] argument: opt_arg2
[-x] argument: opt_arg3
remaining 4 args :
1: man_arg1
2: man_arg2
3: man_arg3
4: man_arg4

br@lorien:~$ ./test-getopt.bash man_arg1 man_arg2 -x opt_arg
[-x] argument: opt_arg
remaining 2 args :
1: man_arg1
2: man_arg2

br@lorien:~$ ./test-getopt.bash -x opt_arg4 man_arg2 -n opt_arg1 -x opt_arg3 man_arg3 man_arg4
[-x] argument: opt_arg4
[-n] argument: opt_arg1
[-x] argument: opt_arg3
remaining 3 args :
1: man_arg2
2: man_arg3
3: man_arg4
```

EDIT: Rewrote the code into a function, as asked in question.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, thanks for the answer! Could you explain what the first 4 lines of the function do please (the lines below)
```SOPTS="n:o:x:"
    TMP=$(getopt -o "$SOPTS" -n "$CMD" -- "$@") || exit 1
    eval set -- "$TMP"
    unset TMP```

Comment: I did add some comments; let me know if they are clear enough

Comment: Thanks so much! That's very clear

Comment: Don't forget to accept a solution, if you think it answers your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

POSIX convention is that non-option arguments to a command must come *after* all options and option arguments. The POSIX `getopts` utility is designed around this convention, so **if you don't want to insist on conventional argument order then `getopts` is not a good fit**.  It might still be possible to make `getopts` work in that case, but I wouldn't try to do so.

If you are willing to depend on [the GNU version of the `getopt` utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html) (not to be confused with `getopts`, with an `s`), then it can accommodate you.  By default, it recognizes options anywhere on the command line, including after non-option arguments.  That might look like this:

```
args=$(getopt --name "$0" --options n:o:x: -- "$@")
eval set -- "$args"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case "$1" in
    -n) n_argument=$2; shift 2;;
    -o) o_argument=$2; shift 2;;
    -x) x_argument=$2; shift 2;;
    *)
      # Handle non-option argument $1 ...
      shift
    ;;
  esac
done
```

But note that **you can do much the same without `getopt`**.  What `getopt` (or `getopts`) does for you is:

- normalize ganged options (`-abc` equivalent to `-a -b -c`; only for options that do not require arguments)
- normalize option / argument separation (`-xfoo` equivalent to `-x foo` when option `x` takes an argument)
- recognize and accommodate the significance of argument `--` for indicating that only non-option arguments follow
- recognize errors in the arguments, especially the omission of option arguments where they are required
- similar to the above for GNU-style long options (GNU `getopt` only)

If you're not interested in any of that, or if you're willing to roll your own for the ones of those that you want, or if you can't rely on having the GNU version of `getopt` then you can use a loop similar to the above without first using `getopt` to massage the argument list, and without involving `getopts`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that makes things very clear!